# C scaled Integer

Tags: c, security, pointers

So I've read that in C it's not recommended to add or subtract a scaled integer to an pointer, because it is not secure. Arbitrarily code could be executed, because the pointer could be out of address range. Can someone explain me, what an scaled integer in detail is, and what's its purpose?
I didn't find any trustful source, so maybe someone of you could help me.

Url of source: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152330#content/view/87152330

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please cite the source of that information.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the source in the question.

Comment: It seems to be a warning that pointer arithmetic uses the size of each element internally, so that it works in the same way as array indexing. Then `int n = arr[2]` is the same as `int n = *(arr + 2)`

Comment: @Waether Vane But do you know or can you explain what a scaled integer is?

Comment: An array index is an example of a scaled integer. For a 32-bit integer array, a unit of 1 represents 4 bytes from the base address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that the source seems to be using the terms "scaled" and "converted" interchangeably.

The scaling that they refer to in one sense is the scaling performed only in the context of pointer arithmetic. For example:

```
int buffer[5];
int *pi = buffer;
pi += 2;
```

The address initially pointed to by `pi` is a single byte or `char`. But when 2 is added to it, the address is advanced by 8 or 16 bytes, depending on whether the system is a 32-bit or 64-bit system. This is because the size of `int` is either 4 or 8 bytes. So the actual value that is used is said to be scaled.

The other sense for the use of the term "scaled" in the source is when it refers, for example, to a `size_t` value being "scaled by int", and then being scaled again.

This is confusing, because what it really means is that the `size_t` value is converted to `int` (for legal pointer arithmetic), and then scaled in the context of that arithmetic.

Where this becomes a problem for pointer arithmetic, is of course, whether or not the conversion loses information.

The main thing to remember about pointer arithmetic is to always be certain that the value that you think you are using -- is in fact the value that you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the first part I've understood, but the second part is really confusing as you have already written. So the `size_t skip` variable holds the offset of the struct member `ull_b`. It has a size of 8 Bytes because of the `long long` datatype of struct member `ull_a` (This is the first scaling right?). After that the scaled offset `skip` is added to the struct pointer `struct test *s` and now pointer arithmetic is doing a second scaling? (scaling from 8-Byte `long long` to 32-Byte `struct big`)?

Comment: See, that's the confusing part about the way they use the terms. `skip` is still an 8-byte `long long`, but it's *value* (let's say 4) is scaled to mean `4 * sizeof(struct test)` instead of `4 * 1 byte`.